# I'm trying to print the digits of a given integer as a word. Ex: input:123, Output: One Two three

Tags: mips32

.data
arr: .space 40
Zero:   .asciiz "Zero"
One:    .asciiz "One"
Two:    .asciiz "Two"
Three:   .asciiz "Three"
Four:   .asciiz "Four"
Five:   .asciiz "Five"
Six:    .asciiz "Six"
Seven:  .asciiz "Seven"
Eight:  .asciiz "Eight"
Nine:   .asciiz "Nine"
prompt: .asciiz "Enter a number:"
End:    .asciiz "\n End of program"
Invalid:.asciiz "\n Invalid Entry"

## ------------------------------------------------

.text

## Storing string of numbers in the array

la $a1, arr
la $s0, Zero
sw $s0, 0($a1)
la $s0, One
sw $s0, 4($a1)
la $s0, Two
sw $s0, 8($a1)
la $s0, Three
sw $s0, 12($a1)
la $s0, Four
sw $s0, 16($a1)
la $s0, Five
sw $s0, 20($a1)
la $s0, Six
sw $s0, 24($a1)
la $s0, Seven
sw $s0, 28($a1)
la $s0, Eight
sw $s0, 32($a1)
la $s0, Nine
sw $s0, 36($a1)

## ------------------------------------------------

addi $t4,$zero,0#variable for storing reversed number
li $v0,4
la $a0,prompt
syscall

## getting the number

li $v0, 5
syscall

## Storing the number

addi $t0,$v0,0
blt $t0,$zero,IE

## reversing the number

reverse:
beqz $t0, continue
and $t1,$t0,9 #Applying the modulus operation to get the last digit of the number
divu $t0,$t0,10#Removing last digit of the number
mul $t4, $t4,10 #reverse=reverse*10
add $t4, $t4, $t1 #Adding last digit
j reverse

## ------------------------------------------------

continue:
and $t3,$t4,9 #Applying the modulus operation to get the last digit of the number
la $a0, arr($t3)
li $v0, 4
syscall
div $t4,$t4,10
beqz $t4, Exit
j continue

## ------------------------------------------------

IE:
li $v0,4
la $a0, Invalid
syscall

## ------------------------------------------------

Exit:
li $v0, 4
la $a0, End
syscall

## ------------------------------------------------

Can somebody point out the errors?